# How to select complete paragraph with selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, c#, testing, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I want to select a whole paragraph and then the selected text of this paragraph appears in a text area. I tried many solution but it selects from middle to the end or middle to the start of the paragraph.
I have this paragraph:

```
A paragraph is a self-contained unit of a discourse in writing dealing with a particular point or idea. A paragraph consists of one or more sentences. Though not required by the syntax of any language, paragraphs are usually an expected part of formal writing, used to organize longer prose.
```

Now i want to select this complete paragraph by using below code:

`Actions context = new Actions(driver);
context.MoveToElement(heading).ClickAndHold(heading).MoveByOffset(170, 55).KeyUp(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.LeftShift).Release();`

But this code select only that part of the paragraph which i make italic. Please help me to select the whole paragraph.